# How to force HttpPost attribute for all actions

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I would like to force all controllers actions to work with `HttpPost` only.

I know that I can specify `[HttpPost]` at the top of the controller but I want to do it from the `register` function or something like this for all the app.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

create a basecontroller, decorate it with the [HttpPost] and make sure all your api controllers inherit from that basecontroller

Comment: [HttpPost] can decorate only methods, not a class